# vim paste multilines before multilines, no Blank

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Let's say I have these two blocks:

```
1
23
456

hello..
world world
codecode
```

And then I need this block (between *1* and *hello..*, without any spaces between):

```
1hello..
23world world
456codecode
```

What is the best fast way?

---

I used gvim7.3.46 on windows xp and windows 7

this is my _vimrc

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

---

I used `C-r"`, but that did not work.

```
1
23
456
hello..
world world
codecode
```

---

I used `C-q`, `y`, `C-p`, the result is:

```
1
23
456

1  hello..
23 world world
456codecode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Place the cursor on `1`.
2. Hit `<C-v>` to enter visual-block mode.
3. Move the cursor down to `456` and hit `$` to select the whole block.
4. Hit `y` to yank that block.
5. Place the cursor on the `h` in `hello`.
6. Hit `P`.

Comment: Using your sample I get exactly what you are asking for: with no space. Post your vimrc to see if there's a setting that prevents this very simple and straightforward solution to work. Also, the way to do it in first step is to record a macro. If you want "one step", ask "one step".

Comment: I found that on my windows os gvim4.7a,when I use `ctrl-q` `ctrl-c`(copy) `ctrl-v`(paste),the two blocks joined with no space;when I use `ctr-q` `y`(or `d`) `P`,it join with blank space;
but I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

I would use **visual block mode**. Do like this:

1. At the start of the first block, press `<C-v>` to enter visual block mode.
2. Select the relevant lines, and press `$` to extend the selection to the end of the line.
3. Press `d` to delete the first block. This will also copy it.
4. Then press `P` at the beginning of the second block to paste the first block before the second block with no spaces in between.

The first line range will then be empty, so you will have to delete those lines if you don't want them.

Comment: Using the method you said, I got
1 hello .. (with a space before hello)
23 world world (with a space before world)
456codecode

Is there any way can do with no spaces, just do it in one step...
, or paste with no blank? Thank you,Lstor

Comment: In that case, you might have extra spaces at the end of the `1`, `23` and `456` lines. Try selecting those lines and run `:'<,'>s/\s\+$//g` to remove any spaces at the end of those lines. You can also `:set list` to show trailing whitespace. When I run the commands in my answer, I get the first block before the second with no (extra) spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive macro to jump back and forth between to two blocks, deleting and joining lines:

```
qq}jdd''pkgJj@qq
```

Notable keystrokes:

- `''` jumps back to the line where you jumped from the most recently
- `@q` calls the macro `q` from inside the definition of `q`
- `gJ` joins two lines without a space between them

[image: recursive macro]